# How to show this integral (Error function)

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

I'm given this question. Show that $$\int_{0}^{0.25}\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}e^{-x}dx=\int_{0}^{0.5}2e^{-u^2}du$$. As I know this integral is an error function. How to show? Can anyone give me some hints? Thanks.

Comment: Did you try substitution?

Comment: Hmm. Let me think. Let $u=\sqrt{x}$. Is this correct?

Comment: Yes, Indeed....

Answer (score 1):

HINT:

As $0.25=(0.5)^2,$

try with $y=\sqrt x\implies dy=\dfrac{dx}{2\sqrt x}$   and  $x=y^2$

Comment: I solved it. Thanks for your hints.